# how to save a raster after converted from numpy array?

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy

I'm trying to save a raster after calculation in numpy array. Here is what I wrote:

```
rasterSM = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(SM, lowerLeft, cellSize, value_to_nodata=nodata)

rasterSM2 = arcpy.DefineProjection_management(rasterSM, spatial_ref)

rasterSM2.save(SMOutputName)
```

But the error message says that 'Result' object has no attribute 'save', then out to save a raster from Numpy array?

Comment: What does the variable `SMOutputName` look like?

Comment: SMOutputName = "Y:\\MODIS_Sep\\" + "SM" + str(partName)+ ".tif"    and the partName is a number.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are trying to save a non-raster object `rasterSM2`. Instead, try `rasterSM.save(SMOutputName)`. Once that is complete then define the projection using `arcpy.DefineProjection_management(SMOutputName, spatial_ref)`

Comment: @Aaron Thank you Aaron! It worked! rasterSM = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(SM, lowerLeft, cellSize, value_to_nodata=nodata)
    rasterSM.save(SMOutputName)
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(SMOutputName, spatial_ref)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to save a non-raster object `rasterSM2`. Instead, try:

```
rasterSM.save(SMOutputName)
```

Once that is complete, then define the projection using:

```
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(SMOutputName, spatial_ref)
```